# RegExp for finding repeated complete strings (two-level greediness)

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I have a (perhaps complicated) RegExp question.
A tool that generates files from models says my model uses a name twice, but does not say which name this is.
I know that all the names in question start with "CK_", followed by some non-whitespace.
I prepared this test-file:

```
CK_123abc
foo
CK_abc
CK_123abc
CK_199
bar
CK_177
bar
CK_188
```

As you can see "CK_123abc" appears twice. I want to catch all those (if there are more) with a RegExp. I got this one so far: **(CK_\S*).+\1**

This works fine and matches the following text:

```
CK_123abc
foo
CK_abc
CK_123abc
```

but it also matches

```
CK_199
bar
CK_177
bar
CK_1
```

The 2nd, **unwanted** match is for **CK_1**.
As my real document is full of these "half-string"-matches, I can't find my real match (like the 1st one here) in the data.
I think that **(CK_\S*)** for some reason is not greedy - or that the whole regex is greedy. For my use case to work, **(CK_\S*)** has to match as much as possible first, then the same match should be found later in the document.

I'm using Notepad++ (with PCRE). **"."** matches **"\r"** and **"\n"**.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the greediness or the lazyness of the quantifiers, but the way the regex engine works. The regex engine, when a pattern fails, has the possibility to use the [backtracking mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) to try other possibilities *(until the pattern succeeds, or until there is no more possibilities)*, and that, from a same position in the string.

The only way to moderate this behaviour is to add more contraints in your pattern *(to limit possibilities)* as you can see in several answers here.

The idea is to check the limits *(left and right)* of the names using spaces, [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) or [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) without to forget to do the same for the backreference:

with spaces: `(?:\s|^)(CK_\S*)(?=\s.*(?<=\s)\1(?:\s|$))` *(a bit long, but probably the most waterproof way)*

with word boundaries: `\b(CK_\S*)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)`

with possessive quantifiers *and word boundaries*: `\b(CK_\S*+)(?=.*\b\1\b)`

Note: since the dot is used, you need to switch on the singleline mode for all the patterns.

Answer (score 2):

If you anchored the `(CK_\S*)` to a space character, it will match as much as it can:

`(CK_\S*)\s.+\1`

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
(?s)(CK_\S+\b)(?=.*\1)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/14).

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `(CK_\S+\b)` captures your token to Group 1
- The lookahead `(?=.*\1)` asserts that what follows is any number of chars, followed by what was captured by Group 1

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about 
    (CK_[^\n]*).+\1
So you would take everything till the newline which is what you would want.

Comment: That one suffers the same problem as my initial version.